# NSPopUpButton + Bindings + Show All Option

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller, nspopupbutton

I'm trying to develop a `NSPopUpButton` that will serve as a filter to some datasource, let's say a `NSArrayController` that fills a table.

I can bind the `NSArrayController` from the menu to the selection keypath so the data is properly filtered, no problem with that.

Tricky part is, I want the content of this `NSPopUpButton` to rely on an `NSArrayController` using bindings, but I'd like to add a "Show All" menu item, or at least some item that doesn't come from the Core Data and performs some special action other than filtering the table using bindings and core data.

I'm trying to perform something like the `NSPopUpButton` used by finder in the filter bar, the last item of the menu performs a special action, while the others just filter the result.

I understand that the approach is to forget about bindings and do it everything programmatically, because I believe there's no way to mess up with the `NSArrayController` and bindings to add this custom menu item that doesn't rely on core data, but since I haven't found anything on the Apple Docs and here, I'd like to share my thoughts... any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

sounds to me like you're looking for the NSContentPlacementTagBindingOption.

you edit the NSMenu that's attached to the NSPopupButton as follows

[image: setup of the pop-up menu button's menu]

you then edit the settings on the NSMenuItem you want to have replaced with your array controller contents so that it has a meaningful tag associated with it

[image: settings for the item that is going to be dynamically replaced by bindings]

you then specify that tag as the content placement tag value on the NSPopupButton's bindings for the content/content* bindings.

[image: bindings for the pop-up button itself]