# Dealing with out-of-model menu items in NSPopUpButton

Tags: macos, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nspopupbutton

It is trivial to setup NSPopUpButton's menu via binding with an NSArrayController. A slightly more complicated, but very frequent use case, is to use `NSContentPlacementTagBindingOption` to insert the array items into the menu from a specified index. A nice example of this is given here, [NSPopUpButton + Bindings + Show All Option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405317/nspopupbutton-bindings-show-all-option).

For example, say I have, the following UI which uses a popup to select a column from a table view. Because the column can be added and removed dynamically by the user the menu items need to be synchronised with model,

```
                       _________________
Select table column:  |____None_________|   <--- this is the popup
```

The menu could have the following items,

```
_______________
|    None     |   <-- Out of model item, "None" or empty selection
 -------------    <-- Out of model item, separator item
|  column 1   |   <-- These are dynamically replaced menu
|  column 2   |       item done using bindings and the
|  column 3   |       NSContentPlacementTagBindingOption
|_____________|       option from IB.
```

Notice that there are two **non-model-items** in the menu, they are inserted into the UI in IB before the the content replaced tag. Using the content replacement tag massively simplifies populating the menu and keeping the items synchronised with the model. However, this causes **huge** problems when the uses makes a selection which is outside the content of the bound array: the "None" marker and the the separator item. Because they are outside the array they cannot become selected items. So the popup button's `selected object` binding cannot be use to track selection changes from UI to model.

Has anybody found a successful way of working with `NSContentPlacementTagBindingOption`, NSPopUpButton and non-model (static) items in the menu?

I'm pretty much about ready to give up and populate the menu manually, which would suck.

NSPopUpButton needs to accept two array controllers: one for static content (the none and separator) and the one for dynamic content which works with content replacement tags. This would make all choices valid.

Comment: Pop-up buttons support other selection bindings; in particular, `selectedIndex` should help. Also, even with bindings set up, you can always use target-action to learn when the pop-up has been manipulated and query it for its selection. And it shouldn't be possible for the user to select the separator item.

Comment: Yes some creative mix of bindings and target/action is probably the solution. One thing that surprised me is that even when using the selected index binding there are problems because it seems to return in the index of the array controllers item! Hence making the non-model items not selectable. The only way I've managed to get around this is by not binding to any of the "selected" options of the popup and, as you suggested, use target/action. Still don't have a nice clean solution yet, will comment when there!